# Failed to install eslint with react-native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint

I have a react-native project and want to use eslint for style check. But I got below error when run `eslint app/` command:

```
ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y". This can happen for a couple different reasons:
```

> 1. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y is also installed globally. A globally-installed ESLint cannot find a locally-installed plugin.
> 2. If ESLint is installed locally, then it's likely that the plugin isn't installed correctly. Try reinstalling by running the
>    following:
>
>    ```
>    npm i eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@latest --save-dev
>    ```
>
> If you still can't figure out the problem, please stop by https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint to chat with the team.

below is my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.40.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-actions": "^1.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "eslint": "^3.14.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^3.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.9.0",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

I have searched this issue someone say about peer-dependency. And I tried different version combination still not work.

Answer (score 0):

1- install ESLint and your plugins locally in your project. Installing the plugins globally or in the package config is kind of a hack.

2-

```
cd ~/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/
    npm install eslint-plugin-react
```

if this is not working then try to look at here , this may be help you  https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/422